How to access what's inside the "data" key in this JSON?
I have this JSON response (contained in response variable):
{
  "data": [
    {
      "requestedUsername": "string",
      "hasVerifiedBadge": true,
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "displayName": "string"
    }
  ]
}

And I want to get values like "name", "displayName", etc... But I can't figure out how to get to them, because it's located inside a dictionary which, in turn, is located inside an array.
I tried beginning with this:
console.log(response.data[0])

But even it returns undefined . So what would the solution be?

If response.data[0] returns undefined then response does not contain what you think it contains. What do you assign to response?

Where did response come from?  Did you tell it the result was JSON?

Did your call JSON.parse() on your response before accessing its keys?

I solved it. The solution was simple.
console.log(response.data.data[0].name)

Problem solved. Solution:
console.log(response.data.data[0].name)


If the variable "response" indeed has that value you should be able to get them with:
var theName = response.data[0].name;

I downvoted as this should be a comment, not an answer.
